# Is it possible in Blender to create a animated png vertical strip?

Tags: rendering, export

I want to create a png file that is an animation of fire for a Minecraft resource pack. I can render the images as separate files and painstakingly put them together in Photoshop. I would rather see if I can do that in Blender or with another tool?

Here is an example of the desired outcome. Sorry for the size.

[image]

Comment: is that the final quality? upload the high res version and necessary dimensions of the output pngs.  we'll see :)

Comment: possible addon of interest : [Spritify](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Spritify)

Comment: Wonderful @zeffii! That is EXACTLY what I am looking for!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Spritify add-on

[Spritify](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Spritify) is an add-on for making sprite sheets and even animated gifs. It has one external dependency: [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), a command-line tool for editing and creating images.

Answer (score 1):

To do this directly in blender use the **import images as planes** addon.

On the options to import (made visible if you press <kbd>N</kbd> or the gear icon on the right) check the Offset Planes box.

[image]

Choose the Y axis. and set the material to emit

[image]

The images will be imported as a long strip.

Create an output size that is thin and tall, set an orthographic camera and align it with the top view, so that it encompasses all of the images in the sequence.

Render as usual.