# How to emit Smoke from an Object?

Tags: rendering, mesh, smoke-simulation

In Maya, there is a tutorial showing emitting smokes from a sword mesh, and then he generates a flipbook of it. What's the name of this and How do I do it in Blender?

The tutorial doesn't show it from scratch, just showed this but didn't explain anything about it.

[image: Sword "emitting" smokes]
[image: flipbook generated]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30390/is-it-possible-in-blender-to-create-a-animated-png-vertical-strip/30411#30411 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5829/how-can-i-export-a-blender-model-as-a-sprite-sheet https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49936/how-to-generate-a-full-sprite-sheet-automatically

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that what i want to know is how to make the sword emit smokes too, and not only create the flipbook.

Answer (score 1):

Simply select the object and in quick effects apply quick smoke in blender