# Exporting PNG Animation sequence in vertical column sprite Sheet

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor

I made an animation of a wheel rotating which is 80 frames. Is there a way I can export my PNG sequence in a vertical sprite sheet, the PNG files stacked one on top of the other like the example I have provided?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: to do this directly on blender read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/188001/92768

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but It seems that Spritify is no longer available.  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Fweeb/blender_spritify/master/spritify.py

Comment: I linked the second answer, not the Spritify one...